# Google Chrome CSS transition text rendering visual glitch

Tags: css, google-chrome, transition, visual-glitch

[image]

I do not know how it has happened, because it worked properly at some point, but after doing some changes, I think to the main scroll container layer of the page, this started happening.

It is a weird visual glitch, I am not able of reproducing it, all that I can say is that the transition is a CSS transition with `transform: translateX()` and that while the transition is running both elements (new and old) get an `absolute` position that its remove once the animation ends. Also, there aren't any `text-shadows` in place.

I does not happen in firefox nor in chrome mobile, and it does not happen always, depends on if I have or not the developer tools opened, I think it might be because of the change in viewport resolution when those are open.

Comment: Could you please provide a working HTML/CSS snippet so we could investigate and help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well;
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zarjqxwk/9/)

Seems it has to do with multiple layers of nested animations.

```
Its a bit to complicated to outline here!
```

Comment: I think the glitch is based on the graphics card of the client device, because I see no issues at all with your fiddle, but I have a semi-decent graphics card (GeForce GTX 1660 Ti)

Comment: Can you size up the window, it seems to be happening more when the window is bigger. Im running a rx580 on a 5k screen.

Comment: I can constantly reproduce it when the viewport in the fiddle is more than 1400px wide.

Comment: even full screen testing the fiddle I see no blurring of the text as described. I have read elsewhere that CSS transitions use graphic card memory fo fluidity so I would still say the issue is based on the client user specs. I can't say if there's a workaround

Comment: Although I agree to a point, it seems it has to do with chrome specifically, as edge is not showing this bug to me.

Comment: Further testing reveals that taking out transform: rotateZ from the animation resolves this, but it is very strange.

Comment: maybe re-ordering the transformations is a workaround?

Comment: Re-ordering did not remove the issue, although removing translate3d and leaving rotateX solved it. Seems an issue involving multiple transforms within transform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240763/discussion-between-viperia-and-martin).